# Javascript multi-language transliteration using a common orthography

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects, transliteration

Due to limitations in direct transliteration between multiple Indian writing systems, I thought about using the Latin script in the middle, so that I can expand the list of Indian writing systems.

At present, I took two Indian writings systems and Latin namely - Malayalam and Tamil.
The Malayalam input is converted to Latin, then the Latin letters are converted to Tamil. Is there a possibility to achieve this using arrays? How will the function/functions be?

My current javascript setup:

```
//malayalam to latin
var ml_to_latin = {  
    mlConsonants:[
        {ml:'ക', lt:'k'},
        {ml:'ഗ', lt:'g'}
    ],
    mlVowels:[
        {ml:'അ', lt:'a'},
        {ml:'ആ', lt:'aa'}
    ]
}
//latin to tamil
var latin_to_tamil = {
    ltConsonants:[
        {lt:'k', ta:'க'},
        {lt:'g', ta: 'க'}
    ],
    ltVowels:[
        {lt:'a', ta:'அ'},
        {lt:'aa', ta:'ஆ'}
    ]
}
```

Comment: you are already using arrays - what is the issue?

Comment: Indeed, but how to get it going? Else I have to resort to writing long regex character replacements.

Comment: just split the string and map each character?

Comment: Yes, like that.